# Joint density of uniform variables on different support

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ where $X$ is uniformly distributed in $[1/3,4/3]$ and $Y$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. I would like to get the probability that $X$ is greater than $Y$.  I assume I need the joint density first which should be :

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}1, & (x,y)\in[1/3,4/3]\times[0,1]\\ 0, & \mathrm{else} \end{cases} $$

According to this, I assume the $Pr(X>Y)$ should be equal to $2/3$ but I am not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniform distribution makes this problem much simpler, as probability is proportional to area of domain.  Graph the square that is your domain. Then graph y=x. The region below/to the right of that line has area equal to the probability you want.  In particular, the area not included is the triangle's 1/2 2/3 2/3 = 2/9, so the answer is 7/9.